# How to get pixel color from oracle VM

Tags: java, colors, virtual-machine, virtualbox, pixel

I have a script written in Java that takes a pixelcolor with the getPixelColor method from the Java Robot class and compares it with another color to see if they are the same. It works fine on my pc, but when i use it in the Oracle VM VirtualBox with a windows 10 installed the pixels always give a white Color. (HSB 0,0,1). 
Is there a way to get the pixel colors from within the vm? Am i missing a setting or should i change my code?

Here are pictures of the code and results:[this is the code that checks if the colors match, with a certain tolerance, it returns a boolean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W2Jr.png)[These are the printed results: if all ToCompare values lie between targetplus and targetmin it will return a true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1kxn.png)

This is my first question so be gentle :).

Comment: It might have to do with the rendering of the virtualmachine. `Robot` is "looking" at a white slate that gets rendered in a special way. If there are settings that affect the hardware graphics rendering of the virtualmachine, turn them off and see if the behaviour changes.

Comment: `Here are pictures of the code` - pictures don't help. Post actual  code. `but when i use it in the Oracle VM VirtualBox with a windows 10 installed the pixels always give a white Color. (HSB 0,0,1).` - post the [mcve] that demonstrates this. The comparison logic is irrelevant. All you need is simple code that uses the Robot.getPixelColor() method and displays the value. Then people using different JVM can test the code to see what results they get. Either the problem is with your code or the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching I've found that the Robot class IS able to get colors from inside the vm, I had made a mistake in other parts of my code and I had some broken functionalities because of multi threading (while the vm runs on 1 thread) which was resolved by changing the vm settings.